# Join table and filter it #mysql

Tags: mysql, filter, join

I have a problem with filtering table after JOIN TABLE. 
As you can see, I have 2 table here.. 
 
Table 1

[image: Image table1]

Table 2

[image: image table2]

I'm doing filter at table 1 without JOIN with Query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id IN (
    SELECT MAX(id) AS id_a 
    FROM tabel1 GROUP BY id_a ) 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

and I got result like this:

[image], its perfectly I want..
Problem is: HOW to JOIN 2 table (table1 and table2) and got result like I'm doing filter table1 like this:

[image: Join Table and filter it]

I hope you understand my question and please help me.

Comment: actually I greet "hi master" in the first line .. but it's gone :o

Comment: wow thanks for GurV 
has made my question look more clear..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pseudo query which you need:

```
SELECT MAX(a.id), a.id_a, a.value, a.datetime,b.weight
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table b ON(a.id_a = b.id_a)
GROUP BY a.id_a
ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

Comment: woooooowwwwww... perfectoooo !! thanks a lot rasel :)

Comment: If this work for you, please upvote and accept the answer to help the future reader

Comment: OK I will do the best sir

Comment: sir, I got a problem with colume value,.
colom value is not following colom id with MAX id..

the result is : id = 25
id_a = 2
value = 3500
datetime = 12/4/2017 09.00